# css animation not rotating the box

Tags: html, css, animation

** why box  not rotating but its translating the box . translateX is working but rotate is not working in animation **

```
<style>
 .box{
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   background-color: red;
animation: animate 1s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes animate{
  0%{
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
</style>

<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add both the transform properties in the keyframe, take a look at the snippet below

```css
.box{
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: animate 1s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes animate{
  0%{
    transform: translateX(100px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateX(0) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: but why this is working ? @keyframes animate{
  0%{
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(100px);
  }
}

Comment: This is because translateX and translateY are both still a translate value -- this is seen by the browser as @keyframes animate{ 0%{ transform: translate(100px, 0); } 100%{ transform: translate(0, 100px); } }

Comment: the browser is computing this : @keyframes animate{
  0%{
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(0);
  }
}

Comment: but when i do like this its working .@keyframes animate{
  0%{
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  100%{
    transform:translateX(0) rotate(360deg) ;
  }
}

Comment: i did not understand how transform working behind the scene ?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. Perhaps you've stumbled upon a bug? Best to be explicit for the start and end values of all the properties you want to animate

Answer (score 0):

This is because it cannot rotate 360deg at the end of the animation.
Almost anything below 360deg will work. Please provide an illustration or video of the result you are trying to accomplish if this solution is not exactly what you want.

```
<style>
  .box {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: animate 1s linear infinite alternate;
  }
  @keyframes animate {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(100px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="box"></div>
```

However if you only want it to spin 360deg and not translateX, you can do it using:

```
<style>
  .box {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: animate 1s linear infinite alternate;
  }
  @keyframes animate {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You cannot link transforms in that way. The second one will override the first one.

Comment: Yes the translateX should be removed from the second code snippet. My bad.

Comment: That is not the full problem. A transform will override any previous transform so if you want two values you must put them in the same transform (ref your first bit of code).

Comment: what does transform : none computes the browser ?